# Calculating $I=\iint_S x^2 \,dy\,dz$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, multiple-integral, surface-integrals

> For $S: x^2+y^2+z^2=R^2$, calculate
> $$I=\iint_S x^2 \,dy\,dz$$

I almost know how to do it. We have for $D_{yz}: y^2+z^2\le R^2$
$$I = \iint\limits_{D_{yz}}x^2(y,z)\,dy\,dz = \iint (R^2-y^2-z^2) \,dy\,dz$$
am I correct or should I see the cases $x \ge 0$ and $x < 0$ and say one time $x = \sqrt{R^2-y^2-z^2}$  and another time $x = -\sqrt{R^2-y^2-z^2}$ and calculate two integrals?

I'm quite confused.

---

$x = R\sin u \cos v, \ \ y= R\sin u \sin v, \ \ z = R\cos u$, then

- $r_u = (R\cos u \cos v, R\cos u \sin v, -R\sin v)$
- $r_v = (-R\sin u \sin v, R\sin u \cos v, 0)$
- $r_u \times r_v = (R^2\sin u \cos v\sin v, R^2\sin u \sin^2 v, R^2\cos u \sin u \cos v - R^2\sin u \sin^2 v)$

Comment: Are you familiar with spherical coordinates as that would be easiest?

Comment: Yes, I am. Could we finish this though? It also appeals since the equation is nice to find $x^2$. But I just hesitate about the signs when finding inverse (actually should I find inverse when I can directly find $x^2$?)

Comment: No but you are integrating over the surface of the sphere so you cannot simply integrate $ x^2 \ dy \ dz$.

Comment: You need to parametrize your surface

Comment: $r_u$ has z-component incorrect. It should be $ - R \sin u$.

Comment: If you do it correctly, you will get $|r_u \times r_v| = R^2 \sin u$

Comment: But for easier working, you should take $x = R \cos u$ instead of $z = R \cos u$ as in my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$S: x^2+y^2+z^2 = R^2$

$dS = \sqrt {1 + (\frac{dx}{dy})^2 + (\frac{dx}{dz})^2} \ dy \ dz$

$ = \displaystyle \frac{R}{x} \ dy \ dz$

As you rightly said, you need to multiply this by $2$. So the integral should be,

$\displaystyle \int_{-R}^{R} \int_{-\sqrt{R^2 - z^2}}^{\sqrt{R^2 - z^2}} 2R \cdot {\sqrt{R^2-y^2-z^2}} \ dy \ dz$

In spherical coordinates, if we parametrize surface as,
$x = R \cos\phi, y = R \sin\theta \sin\phi, z = R \cos\theta \sin\phi$
and we know surface area element in spherical coordinates is $R^2 \sin \phi \ d\phi \ d\theta$, the integral becomes,

$\displaystyle \int_0^{2\pi} \int_0^{\pi} (R \cos\phi)^2 R^2 \sin\phi \ d\phi \ d\theta$

Comment: Aren't you calculating it as a surface integral of the first kind?

Comment: When you told about spherical coordinates, I thought you meant using the formula $$\iint_S \vec F d\vec S = \iint_D \vec F(u,v) (r_u\times r_v) dudv$$

Comment: And when I tried I got an ugly cross product you can see my edit.

Comment: As this is a scalar function, you take $|r_u \times r_v|$ and if you work through it, $|r_{\phi} \times r_{\theta}| = R^2 \sin \phi$